# “Favour object aggregation over class inheritance” is design principal to handle change. how this principal is achieved in adapter pattern?

Tags: oop, user-interface, design-patterns

**But I don't understand it, could someone explain this for me?**
“Favour object [aggregation] over class inheritance” is an important design principal to handle change. how this principal is achieved in adapter pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class Adapter` simply uses an instance of `class A` instead of inheriting from `class A`.

The adapter is basically a shell to `class A` knowing its methods and providing access by decorating A with a different set of methods matching the required contracts by actors using the adapter.

```
interface ListAdapter {
  Object head()
  ListAdapter tail();
}

class SimplestQueue implements ListAdapter {
  private List<?> list;

  public SimplestQueue(final List<?> list) { this.list = list.clone(); }

  public Object head() { return this.list.get(0); }

  public ListAdapter tail() { return new SimplestQueue (this.list.subList(1, this.list.size())); }
}
```

Usage:

```
final ListAdapter queue = new SimplestQueue(new ArrayList());
```

Comment: thanks for your Guidness...and kindly request to you.and also answer this.
“program to an interface not an implementation” is an important design principal to handle change.how this principal is achived in adapter pattern?

Comment: Added an example.

Comment: You'd never want to work agains concrete classes in some general cases:  you are implementing a container for functionality or you are implementing a container for "types". Primitives in your problem domain can be abstracted via interfaces which makes it easier to implement different views on data.

Comment: Thanks for your Help.  Florian Salihovic

Comment: This "You'd never want to work agains concrete classes....." example you mention above is related "program to an interface not an implementation" ???

Comment: Yes it is. I extended my example to show the usage. You'd also not use `ArrayList`, `HashSet` or any other collection implementation for your variable / field declaration.